# Exception - NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.xml.security.Init

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

Hi may i know which library files am i missing in order to solve this exception ? Please help, thanks.

included : xmlsec-1.4.3

```
ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException:701'
com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.xml.security.Init &#40;initialization failure&#41;
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:701)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm._jsp._newlistener._jspService(_newlistener.java:223)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.xml.security.Init (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:168)
    at com.rexit.easc.SoapSender.sentSOAP(SoapSender.java:93)
    at com.rexit.easc.testingXML.checkIsmNcd_value(testingXML.java:2815)
    at com.rexit.easc.testingXML.proc_MOTOR(testingXML.java:517)
    at com.rexit.easc.testingXML.processInput(testingXML.java:269)
    at com.ibm._jsp._newlistener._jspService(_newlistener.java:182)
```

Comment: `xmlsec-1.4.3`is OK. Where do you have added it? Where do you run your app?

Comment: Hi @Jens, i included this library file in my workspace ->web-inf->lib and im running at websphere application v8.51 with java compliance level 1.7 .. shold i try to get the latest version(xmlsec-1.5.3) library?

Comment: `web-inf` must be uppercase: `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Reminder for next quesitons: please paste the errors as text. Do not post errors as images.

Comment: @Jens , yeap it is uppercase WEB-INF .. may i know will it be version matter?

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna noted with thanks.

Comment: Looks like a class loader problem. Where are you other third party libs are located? Also in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Yes @Jens .. all my library file are inside `WEB-INF/lib` .. hmm, i will try with the new version of `xmlsec-1.5.3` and see what's the result.

Comment: Try cleaning your project if you're using eclipse. `Project -> Clean`

Comment: @chsdk i confirm that there's only 1 xmlsec . Beside to
user1354678 , i did this too .. rebuild whole project yet still the same ... 

updated my web-inf files library

Comment: Was this resolved? If so, please let me know how you did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that Init class can not be initialized (first loaded in JVM), it says `initalization failure`. From the code the only thing that happens during class initialization (some static code to be called)  is creating Log. According to [this article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/ctrb_classload_jcl_conf.html?cp=SSAW57_7.0.0%2F1-12-12-2-1) IBM WebShere has built-in Apache commons logging. LogFactory might not be created because of WebSphere configuration.